# Accessing years within a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe wherein there is a column of datetimes:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=4, freq='500D')
print(rng)
df = DataFrame(rng)
```

which looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

I would like to find the mean year from this column, which would be 2012.75 (I would later round it).

Towards this end, I can access an individual year using

`df[0].iloc[0].year`

which returns `2011`

...but to take a mean, I'd have to do this in a clumsy loop. Is there a way to do access these years, then take a mean, which is consistent with Pandas vectorized nature?

Answer (score 2):

If you convert the column into a [DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), then you can use its `year` attribute (which returns a NumPy array) and the array's `mean` method.

```
In [104]: pd.DatetimeIndex(df[0]).year.mean()
Out[104]: 2012.75
```

Another way is to use the [dt accessor](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#dt-accessor) (new in Pandas 0.15):

```
In [132]: df[0].dt.year.mean()
Out[132]: 2012.75
```

Or, if you want to do some [NumPy datetime64 wrangling](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html):

```
In [115]: (df[0].values.astype('<M8[Y]').astype('<i8')+1970).mean()
Out[115]: 2012.75
```

---

For all but small DataFrames, using pd.DatetimeIndex is fastest:

```
In [144]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10**5, freq='500D')

In [145]: df = pd.DataFrame(rng)

In [147]: %timeit pd.DatetimeIndex(df[0]).year.mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.5 ms per loop

In [146]: %timeit (df[0].values.astype('<M8[Y]').astype('<i8')+1970).mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.14 ms per loop

In [148]: %timeit df[0].dt.year.mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.18 ms per loop
```

Comment: this is a great solution...but for some reason I keep getting `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'`. Hummm...

Comment: `df[0]` is a Series, but `pd.DatetimeIndex(df[0])` is a DatetimeIndex object with a year attribute.

Comment: gr8! (their is a slight speed penalty, but very tiny), and syntactically its nice and clear!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways. I prefer the first method that I'll show you. It's easier to read, IMO.

#### setup the data

```
import pandas
import numpy

N = 15
numpy.random.seed(0)
dates = pandas.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=N, freq='200D')
values = numpy.round(numpy.random.normal(size=(N, 2)), 2)
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=values, index=dates, columns=['A', 'B'])
print(df)


               A     B
2011-01-01  1.76  0.40
2011-07-20  0.98  2.24
2012-02-05  1.87 -0.98
2012-08-23  0.95 -0.15
2013-03-11 -0.10  0.41
2013-09-27  0.14  1.45
2014-04-15  0.76  0.12
2014-11-01  0.44  0.33
2015-05-20  1.49 -0.21
2015-12-06  0.31 -0.85
2016-06-23 -2.55  0.65
2017-01-09  0.86 -0.74
2017-07-28  2.27 -1.45
2018-02-13  0.05 -0.19
2018-09-01  1.53  1.47
```

#### preferred way

```
df.resample('1A', how='mean')


                A      B
2011-12-31  1.370  1.320
2012-12-31  1.410 -0.565
2013-12-31  0.020  0.930
2014-12-31  0.600  0.225
2015-12-31  0.900 -0.530
2016-12-31 -2.550  0.650
2017-12-31  1.565 -1.095
2018-12-31  0.790  0.640
```

#### Other way (probably was `resample` does under the hood)

```
print(df.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('1A')).mean())
                A      B
2011-12-31  1.370  1.320
2012-12-31  1.410 -0.565
2013-12-31  0.020  0.930
2014-12-31  0.600  0.225
2015-12-31  0.900 -0.530
2016-12-31 -2.550  0.650
2017-12-31  1.565 -1.095
2018-12-31  0.790  0.640
```

#### Bonus third way

```
df['year'] = df.index.year
print(df.groupby(by=['year']).mean())
          A      B
year              
2011  1.370  1.320
2012  1.410 -0.565
2013  0.020  0.930
2014  0.600  0.225
2015  0.900 -0.530
2016 -2.550  0.650
2017  1.565 -1.095
2018  0.790  0.640
```