# Apply where function [SQL like] on datatime Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like:

```
         Date/Time       Byte
```

0               2015-04-02 10:44:31                       1 
1               2015-04-02 10:44:21               10 
2               2015-04-02 11:01:11                  2 
3               2015-04-02 11:01:21              20

I wish to print all rows related to:

2015-04-02 at 11h

I tried many different solutions but with no results
df is my DataFrame.

For istance to print only flows related to 11 I tried the following: 
res = df.loc[df['stamp'].hour == 11]

With error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'

How can I extract all rows related to a specific hour? 
How can I extract all rows related to a specific hour of a specific day?

Thanks, have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pd.to_datetime() on your timestamps if they are stored as strings.

Then you can do

```
df[df['a_date_col'].apply(lambda x: x.hour) == 11]
```

Or you can use the .dt accessor:

```
df[df['a_date_col'].dt.hour == 11]
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#dt-accessor

[Accessing years within a dataframe in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961805/accessing-years-within-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: I tried the second option:  "df[df['a_date_col'].dt.hour == 11]" but python returns: 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: @SilvestroDaniloGiordano What version of Pandas are you using?  It's a relatively new feature.  http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html